# Why use virtual+override if can change derived method without those?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, overriding, virtual

I know this question has been asked many times but I still cannot find a straight answer.
Why use a method with the virtual keyword and then the override keyword in the derived class if I can change the derived method without those keywords?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Furniture furn = new Furniture();
        furn.SayWhoYouAre();

        Table tab = new Table();
        tab.SayWhoYouAre();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Furniture
{
    public Furniture()
    {

    }

    public void SayWhoYouAre()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm Furniture");
    }
}

public class Table: Furniture
{
    public Table()
    {

    }

    public void SayWhoYouAre()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm Table");
    }
}
```

The above code writes to screen:

```
I'm Furniture
I'm Table
```

So clearly, the table object is a Table AND a Furniture (so polymorphism is taking place) and the `SayWhoYouAre()` method is overriden in the derived class.

Comment: Run this.. `Furniture furn = new Table();
        furn.SayWhoYouAre();` and see

Comment: *so polymorphism is taking place* no, it's not you just calling  `Furniture.SayWhoYouAre() ` and then `Table.SayWhoYouAre()` there is no  polymorphism  involved

Comment: You're not overriding the method, you're replacing it. Take a look at the intellisense, you will see a warning saying ```SayWhoYouAre hides inherited member Furniture.SayWhoYouAre```. If that's intended, you should change your method to ```public new void SayWhoYouAre``` in the ```Table``` class.

Comment: The docs give a pretty thorough overview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Comment: @imsmn It's worth mentioning that adding `new` to the method will only suppress the compiler warning.  The behavior would still be the same (i.e. `Furniture.SayWhoYouAre()` would still be called if the `Table` was declared as a `Furniture` object).

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you have the below scenario. You will get output as I'm Table. if you us the override keyword with the method. Otherwise it will always call the Base class method and give output I'm Furniture. Its called the runtime polymorphism.

```
Furniture furn = new Table();        
furn.SayWhoYouAre();
```

Note: You cannot use `override` in derived class without declaring the base class method `virtual`

Comment: Agreed, but if I instantiate `Furniture furn = new Table();` and Furniture's `SayWhoYouAre()` is empty the runtime somehow knows it's now supposed to call the Table's method. Why can't it do that when Furniture's method has some code in it too?

Comment: @Val No, Its not like this. It only depends on `virtual` `override` and `new` keywords. nothing related to empty method or method definition

Comment: @Val That isn't how it works.  Check out [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iQnAKG) of your proposed situation.  `Furniture.SayWhoYouAre()` is empty, and as a result there is no output from either object, since they were both declared as `Furniture`.

Comment: But I've tried running the code. After instantiating `Furniture furn = new Table();` and calling SayWhoYouAre() I do get a message from Table. But only if the method in Furniture is empty. If it's not then it executes the code from Furniture.

Answer (score 0):

That is not polymorphism.  Your second variable needed to be declared as the derived `Table` to use its `ShowWhoYouAre()` method.  What would happen if you wanted to call that method on an entire collection of furniture, and have each use its specific implementation?

```
var furnitureList = new List<Furniture>();
```

You can add `Table`s to that list (and any other object that implements `Furniture`), but the compiler doesn't know that you will add objects *derived from* `Furniture`.  You've expressed that your collection will contain `Furniture`, so regardless of which implementation of `Furniture` you add to this list, it will only ever call the `ShowWhoYouAre()` method of the base `Furniture` class.

With `virtual` and `override`, this would work correctly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var furnitureList = new List<Furniture>
        {
            new Table(),
            new Furniture()
        };

        foreach (var item in furnitureList)
        {
            item.ShowWhoYouAre();
        }
    }
}

public class Furniture
{
    public virtual void SayWhoYouAre()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm Furniture");
    }
}

public class Table: Furniture
{
    public override void SayWhoYouAre()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm Table");
    }
}
```